# Are individuals empowered to order the police for a free public attorney to represent them during a Terry Stop or non-arrest interrogation?

Tags: united-states, police, lawyer, sixth-amendment, interrogation

Is one allowed to order the police to provide an attorney (6th amendment right) and have the benefit of not being questioned further during a Terry Stop or brief questioning/interrogation where the police did not hand-cuff the individual or tell them they're detained or drive them to a police station?

> A Terry stop in the United States allows the police to briefly detain
> a person based on reasonable suspicion of involvement in criminal
> activity.[1][2] Reasonable suspicion is a lower standard than probable
> cause which is needed for arrest.

Comment: You don't have the "benefit" of not being questioned, but you always have a right to remain silent.  And there's no need of counsel if you invoke this right, so why would you ask for one?

Comment: What is the source oif the quote, please? Was it the Wikipedia article ["Terry Stop"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_stop)